# Regular expression to extract data type and length from string

Tags: regex

I have got the following regular expression and I want to extract the data type and length into groups so that I can act on them.

`^(an|a|n)\..([0-9]*)|(an|a|n)([0-9]*)`

The following data types are all valid:

- `an..70` - meaning alphanumerics up to 70 characters long
- `an3` - meaning alphanumeric exactly 3 characters long
- `n4` - numeric containing four digits
- `n..4` - numeric containing up to four digits

Only 'an' 'n' and 'n' are the valid data types and all can have a '..' range indicator between the type and the number (or not).

The issue I am having is the regular expression doesn't work when I process 'ang..35' since it's matching 'an' in the text, but I want this to be invalid if it cannot find any of the valid data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I process 'ang..35' it's matching 'an' in the text but I want it to be invalid

Then you also want to use an [`$` end-of-string anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

For example:

```
/^(a?n)((?:\.\.)?\d+)$/
```

Comment: That one doesn't work.  I've tried `^(an|a|n)\..([0-9]*)$|(an|a|n)([0-9]*)$` and it work after adding the end of string anchor and it seems to work ok.  Can this be improved upon?

Comment: You didn't say that `a` was a valid data type, and that the length is optional? Also, your regex is missing the second start anchor (or just should be simplified to `^(a|n|an)(\.\.)?(\d*)$`).

Comment: Apologies for missing out the `a` datatype.  Your solution works great.  Thanks for the help!